# WordPress Multisite: Is there any way to login to all sites at the same time?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, multisite

I have a Multisite WordPress setup, where each site is a subdomain.  For example, say we have a domain called MyDomain.com, then each subdomain is site1.MyDomain.com, site2.MyDomain.com ... siteN.MyDomain.com.  For each site, we login with the usual site1.MyDomain.com/wp-admin , and the User/Password is the same for all sites.

My task is to login to each site and do something trivial, and since logging in to each site is what really takes the most time (and logging into all sites happens a lot), i was wondering if there is a way to login to all 50 at once?  Like a plugin or something (i've looked but not found).

So the successful result of doing with would end up with 50 tabs open in the browser, and each is a different site.

Comment: As far as I remember, there should be a "share session" option for WordPress Multisite.

Comment: I am afraid you might need to find a plugin for this functionality - search for Single Sign-On (or SSO) plugins for multisite.  You should find some... here's a starting point https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/single+sign+on/

Comment: I currently use WPMUDEV's SSO and works well for my needs (but I do not have 50 sites, only 4) -> https://premium.wpmudev.org/docs/getting-started/secure-one-click-logins-sso/